# iOS error: No visible @interface for 'Project' declares the selector 'alloc'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am initialising an object like so:

```
Project *Project = [[Project alloc] init];
```

Here's the code for the project class:

**Project.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Project : NSObject
{

}

    @property (nonatomic,assign) int projectID; 
    @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *name; 

@end
```

**Project.m**

```
#import "Project.h"

@implementation Project

    @synthesize projectID, name;

@end
```

**I'm getting the error** `No visible @interface for 'Project' declares the selector 'alloc'` **when I try and initialise the object.** How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You seem to be trying to call a variable the exact same name as the class: `Project *Project`. It's no wonder the compiler is getting confused!

Switch the variable name to lower case, `Project *project`.

Comment: Happens to everybody at least once... At least... For my sake, I hope it does :D

Comment: you saved few moments of hair pulling on my head :-P

Answer (score 7):

Never use the class name as an instance reference name.

```
GoddamnClass *GoddamnClass = [GoddamnClass new]; // will have problems

GoddamnClass *anInstanceOfGoddamnClass = [GoddamnClass new]; // works like a magic
```