# IOS/Objective-C: call of another class(VC) method not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've searched and searched for the answer to this issue and the solutions i've found doesn't seem to work, so I guess i'm doing something wrong: i want to call this method

```
-(void)customFade:(UILabel *)theLabel withDelay:(float)delayAmount {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:delayAmount
                          options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                          animations:^{
                          [theLabel setAlpha:1.0f];
                          [theLabel setAlpha:0];
                          }completion:nil];
}
```

from a VC called View Controller to another but it isn't being recognized despite the imports... here's what i'm trying on the desired VC:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ViewController *ViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    [ViewController customFade:_label withDelay:0.3];
}
```

the warning says "no visible @interface for "ViewController" declares the selector alloc

Can someone help me out? I'm kind of new at this, thank you

Comment: Did you subclass `ViewController` from `UIViewController`?

Comment: Does "ViewController" is having xib or inside storyboard?

Comment: Check if you have declared this method in the interface file (.h file) of the ViewController class.
You might need to expose the method in the interface file of your ViewController clas to access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> such an error usually happens when you have mistyped the name of the method, or that method doesn't belong to that class at all and doesn't exist in your class.

and ensure once your VC is subclass with UIViewController

> @interface ViewController : UIViewController

change your instance object type  and check once

```
  ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];

  [vc customFade:_label withDelay:0.3];
```

and change the animation like

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:delayAmount
                      options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                      animations:^{
                      [theLabel setAlpha:1.0f];

                      }completion:{
                     [theLabel setAlpha:0];
       }];
```

for more information you can get the reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974682/ios-error-no-visible-interface-for-xxxx-declares-the-selector-alloc)

Comment: that was it (vc)...Thanks Anbu and all the others for the tips :)